# How to get the selected Tab of my TabPanel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a `TabPanel` in GWT and add tabs 
Now I want to get the selected tab so that if a user clicks on a close button, I can close that selected tab.

Here is my tabpanel code:

```
    TabPanel tabPanelCvs =new TabPanel();
    tabPanelCvs.setVisible(true);
    tabPanelCvs.setSize("900","800");
    VerticalPanel vpnlCvsTab = new VerticalPanel();
    tabPanelCvs.add(vpnlCvsTab,result.getResumeTitle());
```

Any idea how can I get the selected tab of my `TabPanel`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For getting selected tab of `TabPanel` there is method: [`TabBar#getSelectedTab()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html#getSelectedTab%28%29)

```
int selectedIndex = tabPanel.getTabBar().getSelectedTab();
```